# Exempting Xamarin.Forms iOS App from Microsoft Intune MDM Policy for Share Extension Feature

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, intune, intunemam

I have a Xamarin.Forms iOS app that uses the Share Extension feature to upload files from the attachments of emails in Microsoft Outlook on the device.

My Xamarin.Forms iOS app is distributed via Microsoft Intune with the MDM policy "Send org data to other apps: Policy managed apps" enabled for the managed device.

Although my app doesn't have any integration with the Microsoft Intune SDK and is not a Policy managed app, I still want to use the Share Extension feature in my app. However, when the "Send org data to other apps: Policy managed apps" policy is enabled, the files accessed through the Share Extension feature are corrupted (possibly due to being encrypted).

I want to exempt my app from the "Send org data to other apps: Policy managed apps" policy. In my research, I found this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/apps/app-protection-policies-exception#ios-data-transfer-exceptions

It suggests that I can define unmanaged apps as exempt apps using iOS URL protocols to exempt them from this policy. I tried adding the URL scheme of the iOS project of my Xamarin.Forms app to the exempt app list, but it didn't work. I also added the URL scheme used by the Share Extension to the exempt app list, but that didn't work either. How can I resolve this issue?

**Edit:**

I saw a field called exempt apps in Microsoft Intune. As in the picture below:
[image]

I also added the iOS URL Schema informations from my own project to this area. As follows:

> Default: skype;app-settings;calshow;itms;itmss;itms-apps;itms-apss;itms-services;com.ios.test;com.ios.test.shareextension;com.ios.test.shareextensionui;

- My iOS app URL Schema: "com.ios.test"
- My Share Extension App URL Schema: "com.ios.test.shareextension"
- My Share Extenaion UI URL Schema: "com.ios.test.shareextensionui" ([I used the following approach when developing the UI of the Share extension project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/extensions-with-xamarinforms). For this reason, I also have a Share Extenaion UI project.)

But that didn't work.

Comment: The Policy managed apps with OS sharing value is applicable to MDM enrolled devices only. If this setting is targeted to a user on an unenrolled device, the behavior of the Policy managed apps value applies. Users will be able to transfer unencrypted content via Open-in or Share extensions to any application allowed by the iOS MDM allowOpenFromManagedtoUnmanaged setting, assuming the sending app has the IntuneMAMUPN and IntuneMAMOID configured;

Comment: for more information, [ see How to manage data transfer between iOS apps in Microsoft Intune](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/apps/data-transfer-between-apps-manage-ios). See https://developer.apple.com/business/documentation/Configuration-Profile-Reference.pdf for more information on this iOS/iPadOS MDM setting.

Comment: Thank you @AlexandarMay-MSFT. My device is an MDM enrolled device, and the MDM has the Policy managed apps rule enabled. However, my app that I want to distribute is not Policy Managed, and I want this app to be able to access unencrypted content even though it is not policy managed. Can I achieve this?

Comment: Thanks for your update, I don't think it's possible because transferred data is encrypted by Intune and unreadable by unmanaged apps and also it may need to be Policy Managed.

Comment: However, I saw a concept called exempt apps in Microsoft Intune. If I define my app as "exempt app", isn't it possible that my app can access unencrypted content even if it's not managed by policy? If not, what exactly is the function of the exempt app?
NOTE: I also defined my application as Exempt app (I added what I did as an edit under my question.) This did not work, but I think I did something wrong here.